# Results cannot be retrieved from a CallableStatement before it is executed

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I have this method in my application to get child organizations of a particular organization. It calls a stored procedure(which creates a temporary table).

**StoredProcedureDAO.java**

```
private Connection dbConnection = null;
private CallableStatement cstmt = null;
private ResultSet results = null;
```

**inside getChildrens(int siteId) method**

```
public ArrayList<String> getChildrens(int siteId)
{
    ArrayList<String> childrenSites = new ArrayList<String>();
    Connection pgConnection = getFreshDBConnection();
    if (pgConnection == null) {
        cat.error("getChildrens got a null connection");
        return null;
    }
    try{            
        pgConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        cstmt = pgConnection.prepareCall("{ ? = call \"spGetChildSitesInfo\" ( ? ) }");
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
        cstmt.setInt(2, siteId);
        cstmt.execute();
        results = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(1);
        if(results != null){
            while(results.next()){
                childrenSites.add(results.getString(1));
            }
        }
        cstmt.close();
        pgConnection.commit();
        pgConnection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e){
        try {
            pgConnection.rollback();
            cat.error("SQL Exception has occured while retriving the children", e);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            cat.error("Error while connection rollback: ", e);
        }

    } finally {
        try {
            if(!pgConnection.isClosed()){
                pgConnection.setAutoCommit(true);
                pgConnection.close();
            }
            pgConnection = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            cat.error("Error while closing the connection: "+e);
        }
    }

    return childrenSites;
}
```

I am calling this function on clicking a link in my jsp and everything works perfectly. **The problem occurs when i click the link more than once in between the action. In that case i am getting the following exception**

```
ERROR [StoredProcedureDAO] SQL Exception has occured while retriving the children
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Results cannot be retrieved from a CallableStatement before it is executed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.checkIndex(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.checkIndex(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2400)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.getObject(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2084)
    at com.mycompany.ejb.session.StoredProcedureDAO.getChildrens(StoredProcedureDAO.java:120)
    at com.mycompany.struts.action.SessionFacadeManager.getSelectedSite(SessionFacadeManager.java:495)
    at org.apache.jsp.Clinical.BrowseCases_jsp._jspService(BrowseCases_jsp.java:383)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Adding some more info after experiments

This is my constructor(private)

```
private StoredProcedureDAO() {
        DBManager dbManager = DBManager.getInstance();
        dbConnection = dbManager.getConnection();
    }
```

And here is the getInstance()

```
public static StoredProcedureDAO getInstance()
    {
        if (myself == null)
            myself = new StoredProcedureDAO();
        return myself;
    }
```

I am calling the getChildrens() using the following

```
StoredProcedureDAO dao = StoredProcedureDAO.getInstance();
children = dao.getChildrens(site_id);
```

Now, if I remove the if statement

```
//if (myself == null)
```

in that case i am not getting the exception. 
I am using postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar driver. Can anyone explain me the reason?

Comment: Where is pgConnection being opened?  It's being closed in the sample code, which might account for the problem with the second click.

Comment: @g051051 I have edited my question to show where the connection is opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a multi-threading issue. It seems like you're sharing the the ResultSet member variables between different threads (a servlet (or JSP) can be shared by multiple threads), hence the error. Are you sure you're creating multiple instances of `StoredProcedureDAO`?

Comment: Thanks ivy. It was so obvious that the problem is with threads.Sometimes i become so dumb. I have edited the question with some additional info. Can you edit your answer explaining me the reason.

Comment: I agree with Ryan Stewart; it's smart to use a framework like Spring to handle the thread-safe injection of DAO's in a web context. Your singleton `getInstance()` should be synchronized to make it safe, but the real problem lies in `ResultSet results` being a member of your DAO. You're still sharing this one DAO instance (with the resultSet member) across threads, and each is overwriting the resultSet. The resultSet should be a variable local to your thread!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the sharing of non-thread-safe resources across threads. Stop trying to manage all the database resources manually, and [use a framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) like Spring to handle it all for you. It will save you from yourself.

Comment: Indeed.This is an old application in which i am trying to fix current bugs, so i cannot change the whole design. You are right about using a better framework. I am developing another application using spring it is really good technology

Comment: @anu: I'm not talking about completely changing the infrastructure of your app. Just create a JdbcTemplate and use its [execute()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreator,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCallback%29) methods. It will take care of all the resource management for you.

Answer (score 0):

you should closed the Result in the finally.you can try it .

Comment: It didnt worked initmo. You can read my edited question. tnx anyway